# Spring-boot jersey maven failed to run war file

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, war

We are creating a spring-boot jersey application. 
Now we want to create executable war file. 
The problem is the application runs fine when I run it with

```
  mvn spring-boot:run
```

But when I try to package it to war and run it with java -jar ABD.war
its giving the following error

```
 Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:       /Users/ABC/ABD-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war!/WEB-INF/classes (No such file or directory)


 Caused by: org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.ResourceFinderException:
```

Here are the part of pom.xml I'm using ,

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
.
.
.

 <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>


        <org.slf4j.version>1.7.7</org.slf4j.version>

        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>

        <java.version>1.8</java.version>


  </properties>

.
.
.
.
.
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Although when I unpack the war file I can see the WEB-INF/classes folder is there.

Answer (score 10):

OK found the solution. 
I have a jersery config class, where I added all of controllers class with packages(). 
When I commented it out and  change it to register("controller.class")  It started to work!

```
    @Configuration
    @ApplicationPath("/path")
    @Controller 
    public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
        public JerseyConfig() {
            register(MultiPartFeature.class);
           register(OneController.class);
          //packages("com.controllers");
        }
    }
```

#

Update

#

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OneController.class);

  public JerseyConfig() {
     scan("com.somepackages");
  }

  public void scan(String... packages) {
      for (String pack : packages) {
          Reflections reflections = new Reflections(pack);
           reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Path.class)
           .parallelStream()
           .forEach((clazz) -> {
              logger.info("New resource registered: " + clazz.getName());
           register(clazz);
      });
 }
```

}

#

With this solution you can get all controllers in jersey  register through package scan.

Comment: It seems to be related to a Jersey bug. It could be useful to have a look to this issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1468 and this pull request https://github.com/jersey/jersey/pull/196.