# Jersey bug when starting Spring-boot app Unix style

Tags: jersey, spring-boot

A question has already been posted here at [Spring-boot jersey maven failed to run war file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30406082/spring-boot-jersey-maven-failed-to-run-war-file) and its author has found a work around to get the Spring-boot app to run, but it's still an annoying bug.

Basically, when running a Spring-boot app with a Jersey configuration using ResourceConfig's `public final ResourceConfig packages(final String... packages)` with `java -jar` command or using Unix style `./app.jar start` the following exception occurs:

`java.io.FileNotFoundException:/path/app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war!/WEB-INF/classes (No such file or directory)
 Caused by: org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.ResourceFinderException:`

This does not occur when the app is ran with `mvn spring-boor:run`.

Not using `packages("com.company.app.rest")` is a work around, but it's a pain not to be able to have Jersey scan a base package.

Is this listed as a bug by the Spring-boot team?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is but for some reason nobody complained hard enough. Can you please share your issue on [#3413](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3413)?